# Mysql select recursive get all child with multiple level

Tags: mysql

i have a table

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Folder` (
    `idFolder` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `FolderName` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `idFolderParent` INT(11) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idFolder`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idFolderParent`)
    REFERENCES `Folder` (`idFolder`)
)
```

i fill this table by

```
idFolder , FolderName , idFolderParent
   1           ADoc           Null  
   2           ADoc1           1  
   3           ADoc2           2
   4           ADoc3           3
   5           ADoc4           4
   6           ADoc5           5
   7           ADoc6           4
```

when select a folder with idFolder=1, it should be return all child for this folder and subchild folder(2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7)

When i select a folder id = 4 ==> (5,7, 6)

When i select a folder id = 3 ==> (4, 5,6, 7)

How to do that with one query?

Thx

Comment: Hierarchial queries are awkward in mysql,look into multiple self LEFT joins

Comment: @Mihai MySQL now supports recursive queries: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Please refere this answer if it may helpful.
[Display Parent-Child relationship when Parent and Child are stored in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787100/10883038).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the working one

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idFolder SEPARATOR ',') FROM Folder WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) AS lv FROM Folder
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=1)tmp
WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) a;
```

Look at SQL FIddle here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02b78/1

Comment: thx for this solution.. i need to use the result of this query into other query like : select * from xxx where idFolder IN (your query)! ..is it possible?!

Comment: @Dev Dev put a query around the same to get the required result

Comment: @Dheerendra Kulkarni
Its not working if i add one more row as
INSERT INTO `folder` (`id_folder`,`FolderName`, `idFolderParent`) VALUES (8,'ADoc7', '7')

your query return only 5,7,6 but actual result is 5,6,7,8

Comment: @DheerendraKulkarni the SQL FIddle doesnot work anymore . can you update it ?

Comment: @sh1hab you canchange version of mysql to like 5.6 , build schema and run query

Answer (score 24):

None of the previous solutions worked for me. Both only work if the parents are saved into the database in a certain order.

I have to admit I do not fully understand the way the query works but could find a way that works for me (at least better than the other answers).

The data with which the first and second queries do not work is:

```
idFolder , FolderName , idFolderParent
   1           ADoc           Null  
   2           ADoc1           7  
   3           ADoc2           2
   4           ADoc3           3
   5           ADoc4          Null
   6           ADoc5           5
   7           ADoc6           5
```

If you use the first and second queries in this dataset, for the id 5 you only get as a result '6,7'. But if you use my query you get: '6,7,2,3,4' which is the expected result.

My version:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idFolder SEPARATOR ',') FROM Folder 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(idFolderParent, @pv)) AS lv FROM Folder 
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=5) tmp
) a;
```

Hope it helps someone. I cannot comment nor downvote the other answers because of lack of reputation :(

Comment: This is actually allot better, since it allows you to use parents with both higher and lower id's compared to the children. It even works if 5 has a parent which also is a child. I swapped idFolder and idFolderParent to get only the parents (and not the children of the parents).

Comment: hi, it is working fine when run individually, but when i tried in Stored Procedure then it is showing wrong output, any guess, what can be the reason.

Comment: @Sandeep no idea, but you should try creating a new question with the specific code you are running and the problem you are finding, that way anyone can help you

Comment: @agentprovocateur you should use SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; immediately before your query to increase the character limit.

Comment: THis query takes 11 seconds to run!

Answer (score 8):

Be aware the MySQL treats the

```
idFolderParent IN ('1, 2')
```

as a single value, so it is equal to:

```
idFolderParent IN ('1')
```

so in order to operate on the list, you need to:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idFolder SEPARATOR ',') FROM Folder WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(idFolderParent, @pv)) AS lv FROM Folder
JOIN (SELECT @pv:=1)tmp
WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) a;
```

(the *FIND_IN_SET*)

Comment: but still not give perfect result.

Comment: The last line should be "WHERE FIND_IN_SET(idFolderParent, @pv) a;"

Answer (score 3):

```
select  idFolder, FolderName, idFolderParent
                                from (select * from Folder order by idFolderParent, idFolder) folders_sorted,
                                (select @pv := 1) initialisation
                                where   find_in_set(idFolderParent, @pv) > 0
                                and @pv := concat(@pv, ',', idFolder)
```

@pv := 1 is your current Folder id.. I think this is much better solution.

Dheerendra Kulkarni's answer which is below gives me this error for different collations. I hope this will helps someone.

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
    SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idFolder SEPARATOR ',') FROM Folder WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) AS lv FROM Folder
    JOIN
    (SELECT @pv:=1)tmp
    WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) a;
```

Comment: Hi @Oğuz Can Sertel. the first query i have used and successfully implemented. Thank you. But want some more on that I want to show the child id having a specific data. can you please help me on that.

Answer (score 3):

May be it works if you don't want to main id in result remove SELECT 4 Level UNION from query

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Level SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
SELECT 4 Level
   UNION
   SELECT @Ids := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`idFolder` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `folder` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`idFolderParent`, @Ids)) Level
   FROM `folder` 
   JOIN (SELECT @Ids := 4) temp1
) temp2

Look at SQL FIddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2b4b3/312

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ORDER BY nodes' to get an ordered tree:

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ;

ALTER TABLE `companies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

INSERT INTO `companies` (`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 9, 'B1'),
(3, 9, 'B2'),
(4, 9, 'B3'),
(5, 1, 'B1C1'),
(6, 3, 'B2C1'),
(7, 3, 'B2C2'),
(8, 7, 'B2C2D1'),
(9, 0, 'ROOT'), -- This is the root node
(11, 9, 'B4'),
(13, 5, 'B1C1D1');

WITH RECURSIVE treeview (id, parent_id, name, lvl, nodes) AS
(
  SELECT id, parent_id, name, 0, CAST('0' AS CHAR(10))
    FROM `companies`
    WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, t.lvl + 1, CONCAT(nodes, ',', c.id)
    FROM treeview AS t
    INNER JOIN `companies` AS c
      ON t.id = c.parent_id
)

SELECT id, CONCAT(REPEAT('  . ', lvl), name), lvl, parent_id, nodes
FROM treeview
ORDER BY nodes
```

And this is the output:

[image: Hierarchical structure]

[Check the SQLFiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=924053e5-8302-4578-8cce-43b5cbe499bd)

Answer (score -1):

to get all level child of a particular parent you can use this below query:

```
 select idFolder from (select * from Folder order by idFolderParent, idFolder) Folder, (select @pv := '1') initialisation where find_in_set(idFolderParent, @pv) > 0 and @pv := concat(@pv, ',', idFolder )
```