# How to recursively update fields using triggers?

Tags: mysql, recursion, triggers, sql-update

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
 `idtag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `value` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci,
 `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idtag`),
 UNIQUE KEY `idx_parent_name` (`parent`,`name`), 
 KEY `idx_parent` (`parent`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_parent` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `tags` (`idtag`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is going to be something like an XML structure. Each `tag` can have its parent (or `NULL` in top level) and I want to store when the tag was last modified, for caching purposes. The `UNIQUE` index is to prevent having two same sub-tags within a tag.

Because when I change/add/delete a sub-tag, the parent tag is logically also updated, I wanted to cascade the new TIMESTAMP (field `modified`) update in all parent tags, so I created a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tags_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `tags` FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE `tags` SET `modified` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE `idtag` = NEW.parent;
```

(and the same code for `AFTER UPDATE` and `AFTER DELETE` triggers)

I hoped it would be possible to update all parent tags in cascade way.

This is however not possible in MySQL (eg. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300941/2088851)). I've also tried with `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, but the error is the same.

So my idea is that I will create another table to store timestamps, but I don't know, how to do this recursively (setting a trigger on this another table leads to the same issue).

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

(The database will work with PHP, and I can perform this check there, but there will be no sense for caching if I need to read all sub-tags from the db)

Answer (score 0):

I actually think you could use a trigger and update them with something like this 
Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tags_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `tags` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE tags SET modified=NOW() WHERE idtag IN(
(SELECT @pv:=NEW.parent) WHERE idtag=@pv))
```

If that still doesn't work maybe look into using a stored procedure?

Instead of calling "INSERT INTO tags ..."
You could create a stored procedure and call it like "CALL update_tags(...)"

Your stored procedure could handle the logic for cascaded updates.

Comment: Check out this question for more ideas on how to do a recursive query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363893/mysql-select-recursive-get-all-child-with-multiple-level/28366310

Comment: After you nail down the correct recursive query I think using the IN operator will be the key :)