# SQL - table foreign key to itself

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Its my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
`parentid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

Where `parentid` Refrenced to this table.
I have this data:

```
Id    |    Name     |      parentid
1          Cumputer        0
2          MotherBoard     1
3          Cpu             2
4          Cpu cooling Fan 3
5          Monitor         1
```

Now, I want to select `Cpu cooling fan`'s Id and it's all parents:

```
1
2
3
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id as list FROM `category` a INNER JOIN category b ON a.id=b.parentid
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "all parents"? That requires recursion, especially if you don't have a limit to how "deep" the tree can go. mysql doesn't support recursive queries. you can fake it, as you have, with any number of self-joins, but that's just a hack, not a "solution".

Comment: @Marc Ok thanks. i'll try to solve it in Php by multiple selects. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql select recursive get all child with multiple level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363893/mysql-select-recursive-get-all-child-with-multiple-level)