# Trying to return all columns of child records for a parent record

Tags: mysql

I was searching for a solution by which I could get all the child records for a parent record. **[I found a solution that meet my needs as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28366310/726802)**

Only problem is that the above solution is concatenating the IDs.

**Current Resultset**

It is comma separated of ID column with values = 2,3,4

**Expected Output**

```
ID    Name    ParentID
1      1st       null
2      2nd       1
3      3rd       1
4      4th       2
```

I tried below code.

```
SELECT @pv:=
(SELECT * FROM tblreport WHERE ParentID IN (@pv)) AS lv FROM tblreport
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=2)tmp
WHERE ParentID IN (@pv)
```

and got an error message : **Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

**[My sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0f6c/3)**

Comment: What mysql version are you working with?

Comment: Pankaj, first of all I would say that editing question to change it so **_drastically_** so that it is now an entirely different question is not a good idea. You can always ask a new question. As for your current question it is not clear in what way data from all the child records should be returned? RDBMS are row-oriented and you effectively want to merge several rows into one. Could you specify how that "super-row" should look like?

Comment: right now, they are coming comma separated. But, I am expecting to return all columns of a particular row. Please check this answer for current state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363893/mysql-select-recursive-get-all-child-with-multiple-level/28366310#28366310 and I am looking to return all columns of a row and not just ids comma seperated.

Comment: Why does your expected result contain the `4th`-row (child of 2 which is a child of 1) but not the `5th`-row (child of 3 which is a child of 1)?

Comment: @Pankaj, that answer works because 1) you can easily convert integer to a more generic representation (string) 2) for integer values there is a valid separator character. This is not true in a general case (see `VARBINARY` or `BLOB` types). That's why I ask, how do you expect those columns to be returned in general case. If your case is not general, you have to specify that as well. I don't think your current **Expected Output** is good enough. Because if this is what you really need, what's wrong with a simple `SELECT * from tblreport WHERE PartentId IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ParentId, Id`?

Comment: @SergGr: I am looking to fetch only the nested child records. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @Pankaj, sorry I can't answer because I still don't understand what exactly you want. Probably a good (i.e. more realistic) examlpe of input and output data would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, they are coming comma separated. But, I am expecting to return all columns of a particular row.

You could use `CSV` ids result like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblreport
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
                     SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID SEPARATOR ',') 
                     FROM tblreport WHERE ParentID IN (@pv)) AS lv FROM tblreport
                     JOIN (SELECT @pv:=1)tmp
                       WHERE ParentID IN (@pv)) a));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=cb2418bd396ec63f978bd714a6d57cda)**

## Output:

```
ID  Name    ParentID
2   2nd     1
3   3rd     1
4   4th     2
```

**EDIT:**

If you need also original row you could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SET @var = 1;

SELECT *
FROM tblreport
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
                     SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID SEPARATOR ',') 
                     FROM tblreport WHERE ParentID IN (@pv)) AS lv FROM tblreport
                     JOIN (SELECT @pv:=@var)tmp
                       WHERE ParentID IN (@pv)) a))

UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM tblReport
WHERE ID = @var
ORDER BY ID;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=889987a8e71d8de090a8230318215b7f)**

Comment: Can u please also include the id which is being used to search the child record? as you can see in the expected result set ?

Comment: @Pankaj Please do not edit question in place, because now you invalidated my answer. If you want to extend your question, add **`EDIT`** section and post new requirements.

Comment: it is not including the last row. according to DBfiddle, 5th element

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. But what should the query look like, if I have a relation table because of many-to-many relations?

Answer (score -2):

That output is simply provided by this short query:

```
SELECT * from tblreport WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '2,3,4');
```

Better yet...

Use MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2 -- each has recursive CTE queries which conveniently drill down a hierarchical database tree.

(Do not use CSV, only use separate rows.)

Comment: How will I get the comma separated values?

Comment: I don't know.  _You_ mentioned "2,3,4"; where did that come from?