# Email Thread Database Scheme Optimization

Tags: sql, hibernate

Currently in the initial implementation of our db scheme there is following implementation of email message table:

```
EMAIL_MESSAGE

id replyOfId forwardOfId subject date
1  NULL      NULL        text    11
2  1         NULL        text    12
3  2         NULL        text    13
4  1         NULL        text    12 // new email thread was started in this row
...
```

Currently in order to identify threads there is complex logic which should hit db too many times in order to extract child record by `replyOfId` or `forwardOfId`

It would be good to know in which way this can be optimized.

I've thought about some approach in order to create additional table with following mapping:

```
EMAIL_MESSAGE_THREAD
messageId    messageThreadId
1            11
2            11
3            11
1            22
4            22
```

But not sure whether I really need to go with this approach It would be good to know vision the best way how it can be implemented.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917848/recursion-on-database-query-to-get-hierarchical-result-using-hibernate-java - does this help?

Comment: Thanks  Neville Kuyt for quick suggestion, is it possible to use this recursive query clause with hibernate ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486757/hql-recursion-how-do-i-do-this - two options for Hibernate