# how to fetch all child elements of a parent by giving parent id

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, collections

I want to fetch all users present under a manager by giving manager Id.
My table structure is like given below.

[image]

my tree structure is like :

[image]

Input `user1` my result list should be 
     `user1 =[user2,user3,user4,user5,user6]`

Input `user3` my result list should be `user3 = [user4,user5]`

Input `user2` my result list should be `user2 = [user6]`.

So how can I achieve this result.

updated:

My Entity structure is like below:

[image]

Comment: Could yo share your entities' structure?

Comment: My Entity structure is like:

Comment: You can use recursive queries that are part of ANSI SQL and supported by all DBMS. For more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/39918066/2224047