# MySQL Recursive get all child from parent

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

i have this case using recursive query on Mysql to find lv 2 and lv3 child on one table...
database structure i'm using:

```
id name parent
1    A    0
2    B    0
3    C    0
4    D    1
5    E    1
6    F    2
7    G    2
8    H    3
9    I    3
10   J    4
11   K    4
```

The result i was expecting, when filtering the data, where id=1, it will generate the result i'm expecting.

```
id name parent
4   D     1
5   E     1
10  J     4
11  K     4
```

or this is the illustration.
[image: Illustration]

i've been looking everywhere, and reading this http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/, but i didn't find the result i was looking for..
any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: insert your table name, and the page you linked does not exists

Answer (score -10, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE PARENT = 1
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE PARENT IN 
    (SELECT ID FROM TABLENAME WHERE PARENT = 1)
```

Comment: that was fast,thank you..i was using the same quey,but it seems that i was wrong writing the query on where parent IN(SELECT ID FROM TABLENAME WHERE PARENT = 1). @Ollaw

Comment: This query is NOT recursive!

Answer (score 51):

if you want to get all level child of a particular parent then you should try this

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent
from    (select * from tablename
         order by parent, id) tablename,
        (select @pv := '1') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
```

Comment: Please explain your code segment. Just a piece of code won't be much helpful for users.

Comment: this query is helpful if you want to get all child of a parent and also their child and so on. or simply we can say that this is useful to get recursive data

Comment: Yes this works very fine for all levels. Perfect code

Comment: this will not work if there are many children because the concat function returns string length limited

Comment: @ManojRana It's working fine but Im unable to add where clause in this query like WHERE userType <> 'A'

Comment: perfectly worked, but couldn't understand iota of it, but thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please explain how this works? It would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Here is an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: @ZbigniewJasek do you know how I can modify this query to ALSO return the parent row as the first row?

Comment: @ManojRana do you know how to modify this query to ALSO return the parent row as the first row?

Comment: Does not seem to work on all levels if there are children that have lower IDs than their parents. Any Solution??

Comment: @muaaz Did you find any solution for lower parent ids, Also I have same issue

Comment: unfortunately no. I had to handle all that logic at the code level, and that's really a pain as we can't switch to Oracle at this stage. Note: Oracle supports recursive procedures and functions.

Comment: I have found this article from the stackoverflow comments, It's worked for me [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](https://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql)/ [Hierarchical data in MySQL: parents and children in one query](https://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/)/

Comment: Great. great great . thanks. for saving my time. Thanks.

Comment: RE *lower parent ids*: To be fair, my parent is `7` with children `5`, `6` and `8`, and I got all three children as expected

Comment: The approach seems to have been copied from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query/33737203#33737203, which is where the explanation is

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion the key to finding all children in a hierarchical table structure is to first find the path to the parent, and then use `FIND_IN_SET` to see if the requested node is in the path. It's easier and more efficient to search up than down, because the link to the parent is already there in the table.

So let's start with a hierarchy like this:

```
1 Pets
├─ 2 Dogs
│  ├─ 3 Katie
├─ 4 Cats
│  ├─ 5 George
│  ├─ 6 Pete
│  ├─ 7 Alice
├─ 8 Other
│  ├─ 9 Rabbits
│  │  ├─ 10 Noah
│  │  ├─ 11 Teddy
│  │  ├─ 12 Bella
│  ├─ 13 Rats
│  │  ├─ 14 Henry
```

And now you want to find all children under the category `Other` (with the category included) then the expected result would be:

```
8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

Now let's have a look at the hierarchical path of Henry. The parent for *Henry* (14) is *Rats* (13), which has parent *Other* (8) and finally *Pets* (1). If we use the ID's to make a path for Henry it would look like this:

```
1,8,13,14
```

And this is where the MySQL function `FIND_IN_SET` kicks in. With `FIND_IN_SET` you can filter results where a variable can be found in a comma separated list. In this example we are looking for all children in the category Other (8) and we can simply use `FIND_IN_SET(8, path)`.

To get the path for a hierarchical table I would like to refer to my answer in the post here [MySql: ORDER BY parent and child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382380/mysql-order-by-parent-and-child/68605556#68605556). We will just change the dash to a comma, so we can use the `FIND_IN_SET` function.

The example above would look like this in a hierarchical table:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | parent | name    |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |   NULL | Pets    |
|  2 |      1 | Dogs    |
|  3 |      2 | Katie   |
|  4 |      1 | Cats    |
|  5 |      4 | George  |
|  6 |      4 | Pete    |
|  7 |      4 | Alice   |
|  8 |      1 | Other   |
|  9 |      8 | Rabbits |
| 10 |      9 | Noah    |
| 11 |      9 | Teddy   |
| 12 |      9 | Bella   |
| 13 |      8 | Rats    |
| 14 |     13 | Henry   |
+----+--------+---------+
```

In my approach I will use a procedure that will recursively call itself and keep prepending the path with the parent of the requested `id` until it reaches the `NULL` parent.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PATH`(IN `input` INT, OUT `output` VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN

  DECLARE _id INT;
  DECLARE _parent INT;
  DECLARE _path VARCHAR(128);

  SET `max_sp_recursion_depth` = 50;

  SELECT `id`, `parent`
  INTO _id, _parent
  FROM `database`.`table`
  WHERE `table`.`id` = `input`;

  IF _parent IS NULL THEN
    SET _path = _id;
  ELSE
    CALL `PATH`(_parent, _path);
    SELECT CONCAT(_path, ',', _id) INTO _path;
  END IF;

  SELECT _path INTO `output`;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

We need these results in a `SELECT` query so we need a `FUNCTION` too that wraps the results of the `PROCEDURE`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GETPATH`(`input` INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
BEGIN

  CALL `PATH`(`input`, @path);
  RETURN @path;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now we can use the path in a query. On a table with 10000 rows it takes just over a second on my workstation.

```
SELECT `id`, `parent`, `name`, GETPATH(`id`) `path` FROM `database`.`table`;
```

Example output:

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| id | parent | name    | path      |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1 |   NULL | Pets    | 1         |
|  2 |      1 | Dogs    | 1,2       |
|  3 |      2 | Katie   | 1,2,3     |
|  4 |      1 | Cats    | 1,4       |
|  5 |      4 | George  | 1,4,5     |
|  6 |      4 | Pete    | 1,4,6     |
|  7 |      4 | Alice   | 1,4,7     |
|  8 |      1 | Other   | 1,8       |
|  9 |      8 | Rabbits | 1,8,9     |
| 10 |      9 | Noah    | 1,8,9,10  |
| 11 |      9 | Teddy   | 1,8,9,11  |
| 12 |      9 | Bella   | 1,8,9,12  |
| 13 |      8 | Rats    | 1,8,13    |
| 14 |     13 | Henry   | 1,8,13,14 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
```

And to find all children of Other (8) with Other itself also included we can use the same query and filter with `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT `id`, `parent`, `name`, GETPATH(`id`) `path` FROM `database`.`table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(8, GETPATH(`id`));
```

And finally here is the result. We put a recursion limit of 50 levels in the procedure, but besides that we have no limit in the depth.

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| id | parent | name    | path      |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
|  8 |      1 | Other   | 1,8       |
|  9 |      8 | Rabbits | 1,8,9     |
| 10 |      9 | Noah    | 1,8,9,10  |
| 11 |      9 | Teddy   | 1,8,9,11  |
| 12 |      9 | Bella   | 1,8,9,12  |
| 13 |      8 | Rats    | 1,8,13    |
| 14 |     13 | Henry   | 1,8,13,14 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

If you want to have a single value instead of rows then you might want to use `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) `children` FROM `database`.`table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(8, GETPATH(`id`));
```

Giving you the following result:

```
+--------------------+
| children           |
+--------------------+
| 8,9,10,11,12,13,14 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: why does this not have more votes?? Thank you @Thomas Lobker!

Comment: It would be great if you can handle a recursive loop in case of invalid data...

Answer (score 4):

Try this one , much simple and easy to understand.

(but supports only one hierarchy level)

```
SET @pv = 1;
select * from tablename 
where FIND_IN_SET(parentrecordID,@pv) and !isnull(@pv:= concat(@pv, ',', id));
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one

```
select  id from  (select * from roles order by parent_role, id) roles,(select @pv := '1') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent_role, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
```

but it works for depth 2 only, i need to make it work with more depth since i have 8 levels

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Manoj Rana
[your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726792/10883038) is really helped me a lot.
But I want to use this solution in Hibernate **createNativeQuery();** function. 
Because of **:=** operator I can't able to use. So I prepared new stored procedure using your solution and use it in my code.

You can find The stored procedure which I have created in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787100/10883038)

Comment: the `:=` operator can be escaped in Hibernate's `createNativeQuery` String like this:
`@pv \\:= concat(@pv, ',', id)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for can be this;
https://github.com/ersengultepe/mysql_hierarchy_recursive_procedure/

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS store_procedure_name;
CREATE PROCEDURE `store_procedure_name`(IN cat_id INT)
BEGIN
    declare loopId Int;
    SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
    -- If the value of the category that comes as a parameter is not in the table as parent_id, no further action is required
    IF(select count(id) from category_table where parent_id=cat_id) > 0 THEN

    -- create temporary table
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_category_table (
      `id` smallint(5) unsigned,
      `status` tinyint(3)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
    -- First, save the corresponding value in the temporary table.
    INSERT INTO temp_category_table
    (id, status) 
    VALUES (cat_id, 0);

    -- continue loop as long as the appropriate record exists in the temporary table
    WHILE (select count(id) from temp_category_table where status=0) > 0 DO 
      -- in this section, a record with a status of 0 will be extracted from the temporary table and assigned to the variable loopId
      set loopId = (select id from temp_category_table where status=0 limit 1);

      INSERT INTO temp_category_table
      (id, status)                                       
      (select id, 0 from category_table where parent_id=loopId);

      update temp_category_table set status=1 where id=loopId;

      CALL store_procedure_name((select id from temp_category_table where status=0 limit 1));     

    END WHILE;

    (select DISTINCT(id) from temp_category_table order by id ); 

    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Much faster

```
SELECT * 
FROM table AS T1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE parent = 1) AS T2 
ON T2.id = T1.parent OR T1.parent = 1 
GROUP BY T1.id
```

Comment: Is it recursive?

Comment: and how to add count clause with this query?

Comment: this is NOT recursive