# Get all child and grand child nodes from a specific parent id

Tags: tree, parent-child, union, hierarchy, union-all

I need to get all child and grand child nodes from a specific parent id.

I got the query below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913460/mysql-recursive-get-all-child-from-parent/47260984?noredirect=1#comment81473582_47260984), but it only ends at the 3rd level, i need it to go further.

i have been on this for about two weeks and in need of support.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLENAME
 WHERE PARENT = 1
 UNION
 SELECT * 
 FROM TABLENAME
 WHERE PARENT IN 
(SELECT ID FROM TABLENAME WHERE PARENT = 1)
```

This is a sample of the mysql table

```
 id parent_id name
 1       NULL john
 2          1 Steve
 3          2 sandra
```

john has a parent id of steve, steve has the parent id of sandra, sandra is the grandchild of john.

i hope you understand what i mean here?...

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: i use mysqli to run it

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)