# how to execute multiple mysql queries fast

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am using multiple MySQL select queries for getting the result. The output of the first query is Input of the second query, like this, I am using fifteen(15 queries at the time). Because I want to get a result till the 15th stage.

When I execute all these queries it takes too much time to get the output, for ex- it takes more than 15 to 20 min to produce the result.

Basically, there are 15 levels in my code and I am calculating the total amount for each level and that's why I am using 1 query for each level. So the total level is 15 and my MySql query is 15.

I have a DB table where 4 columns are there-

```
ID, MemberID, SponseredID, Amount.
```

I prepared the query to calculate the SUM of Amount of each Level.

you can check the code below:

```
SELECT SUM(amt) as level1 
FROM adm 
WHERE sid='MT00001';

SELECT SUM(amt) as level2 
FROM adm 
WHERE  sid IN (SELECT mid 
               FROM adm 
               WHERE sid='MT00001');

SELECT SUM(amt) as level3 
FROM adm 
WHERE sid IN (SELECT mid 
              FROM adm 
              WHERE sid IN (SELECT mid 
                            FROM adm 
                            WHERE sid='MT00001'));

SELECT SUM(amt) as level4 
FROM adm 
WHERE sid IN (SELECT mid 
              FROM adm 
              WHERE sid IN (SELECT mid 
                            FROM adm 
                            WHERE sid IN (SELECT mid 
                                          FROM adm
                                          WHERE sid='MT00001')))
```

This is till level 4 and here also these 4 queries take too much time to execute.

I am getting the result but it takes too much time, approx 15 min to execute all 15 queries.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.5

Comment: @Kms the link is for sql server

Comment: @manishsharma what kind of result set you are expecting?

Comment: @James- Mine question is similar to below link but I didn't get expected result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913460/mysql-recursive-get-all-child-from-parent

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`; it used to perform very poorly.

Instead, use `JOIN` or `EXISTS()`, depending on the details of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making subquery for each table, try using `join`.

For your question use `group by` clause for each `group` or `category`.
Search for `recursive query`.

You may use this for your reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017